# User subset filtering for reputation leagues

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

A nice little feature would be the ability to request a "mini-league" view for the reputation leagues.

The view would have the same display as the normal [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow), but would only consider the selected users for the data.

Since this would a power-user feature anyway, it could be implemented as an ability to supply e.g. a specially crafted URL containing the specified user IDs.

The rationale for such a feature would be to further foster friendly rivalry within an organization or a group, therefore increasing their collective contribution to relevant SE sites.

Of course in some group dynamics this might devolve into a pathological situation like rat races for the highest rep, but due to mechanisms present on SE those groups would either become quickly discouraged, or (also quickly) learn the proper participation approaches.

To further clarify, the **intended effects** I hope for:

- **to promote positive, active participation on SE**. If people see that their colleagues regularly participate in SE and do fine, they'll be better motivated to move beyond reading and posting ad-hoc questions.
- **to provide local sources of mentoring on proper SE behavior/etiquette**: having a more experienced colleague (who you know is experienced from your group's league) explaining why your post got downvoted etc. is probably less painful and would lead to a better, quicker reinforcement of preferred behavior. This would hopefully work the other way around as well, i.e. a high-rep user would feel responsible for mentoring people their colleagues who aren't doing so well.

Comment: You could build a query for that in SEDE.

Comment: @juergend: sorry, wanted to address that but forgot. Yes, of course - but a dedicated view would be more usable.

Comment: If anything, I think that people care about their reputation numbers too much, and not too little.  We don't need to give them more ways to care about reputation.

Comment: @SamIam: we can all be disturbed or even angry about how a little number influences our motivation, but we can't deny that it's an effective heuristic for that goal :p. I've edited the proposal a bit to hopefully better explain the motivation behind the proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this draws too much emphasis on the competitive nature of Stack Exchange.

Yeah, we get and love rep, but that's there only as an incentive to ask and answer questions. Gamification is a means to an end, and introducing extra leagues puts to much emphasis on it.

Then, not only is Stack Exchange not about magical internet points, but it's also not about individual users. Stack Exchange sites develop fantastic communities, and that's a really awesome feature of them, but there are no systems in place to introduce cliques, which I feel like this would do.

The global reputation leagues are fine because they emphasize community: maybe you're a low-rep user, maybe you're a high-rep one, but either way, you're somewhere on this list. If you post a lot of awesome content, then you might even find yourself at the very top of that list. Everyone can feel directly involved.

Even though I know you're not in any way talking about removing existing functionality, I'm just not sure what this would bring us. It seems like the only viable outcomes result in less of a sense of community.

In some ways, also, leagues like this would remind me of a social network, which as we all know, Stack Exchange is not, and will (probably) never be.

So, maybe, I guess I can see how it could be fun to compete with friends. But I think that's better done through your own mechanisms, rather than being built into the system natively.

Comment: Well, even if I disagree with the concern about the loss in a sense of community, it's a legitimate one, and since I'm obviously unable to explain the merits of the proposal in a better, +1 for this. Well, looks like I will have to make an SEDE query then.